# Is it possible to pass params to an iOS app that can be evaluated immediately after installation?

Tags: ios

I want to create a different experience based on where they found the link that took them to the App Store. So when the user opens the app for the first time, I want to parse the params if there are any to display some message that continues the experience. Is this possible?

Comment: Interesting scenario. Unfortunately I am afraid it is not possible to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, your app has no information about where the buyer came from when they found your app or when he bought it.